# Large CSV import in Spyder variable explorer crashes the IDE

Tags: dataframe, import, spyder

When I import a large CSV (25 MB) via the Variable Explorer into Spyder, the tool crashes. When I import via the editor it works. However, sometime I need to view the csv and that's why I like to utilize the Variable Explorer. How do I improve performance?

I want to import a csv and look at the df. Spyder crashed.

Comment: I just tried to import a large CSV (which loads in seconds with pd.read_csv) into Spyder 5.4.3 and it hangs for me too. I couldn't see [an open issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) for this, so if you've tried the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ), you could open one.

Comment: I believe I know why: My file is imported as an array. https://pasteboard.co/AwDRUfumHBUh.jpg Could it be that if the import was done as a dataframe it'd worked. However, that option is not available via the Variable Explorer option. https://pasteboard.co/OAMrEPy6ewiN.jpg Is that understanding correct?